# linux shared libraries performance local v nfs

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

What are the performance implications for a Linux binary using shared libraries as seen via ldd which are on nfs mount rather than local disk ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. Here is the information you need:

To address the question of which is faster, you must be clear about what you mean by "faster". In general, you can use two key metrics to quantify the performance of a disk I/O path:

- I/Os per second (IOps)
- Latency

IOps measures how many I/O requests can be satisfied by the disk I/O path in a second.

I/O latency "also known as I/O response time" measures how fast an I/O request can be processed by the disk I/O subsystem.

NAS Storage Systems almost always come out a loser when it competes with DAS on I/O latency. I said almost because Drive speeds and Raid Configuration can be game changers. But same speeds and same raid configuration:

> Local gonna beat NAS

.